# Javascript RegEx quote

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm having trouble getting this Javascript Regular Expression to work.
What i want is to find a character that starts with `@"` has any characters in the middle and ends with `"`. I will also need it in a single quote from.

The tricky part for me, is that it cant be starting with `@"` and ending with `"` because the string it's looking through could look like `[UIImage imageNamed:@"glass-round-red-green-button.png"]`.

So far what i have is this.

`regex: new RegExp('\\@"?\\w+\\b"*', 'g')`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this regular expression:

```
/@(["'])[^]*?\1/g
```

An explanation:

- `@(["'])` matches either `@"` or `@'`
- `[^]*?` matches any arbitrary character (`[^]` contains all characters in opposite to `.` that doesn’t contain line-breaks), but in a non-greedy manner
- `\1` matches the same character as matches with `(["'])`

Using the [literal RegExp syntax `/…/`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) is more convenient. Note that this doesn’t escape sequences like `\"` into account.

Comment: Perfect! Can you give me one more regex please. I need to find a digit, but only if the character before it is not an alphabetical letter.

Comment: @cnotethegr8: I would use a look-behind assertion. But as JavaScript doesn’t support look-behind assertions, you’ll need something like this: `/(^|[^a-zA-Z])\d/`. You may replace `[^a-zA-Z]` with `[\W\d_]` (non-word, digit characters, and `_`).

Comment: Thanks. Its almost done. Im using this `/(^|[\W\d_])\d+/g` but when the digit looks like this `(19` it includes the `(` how can i get that out?

Comment: @cnotethegr8: The problem is with *g* you don’t get a single match but all matches. And these don’t contain an array of matches of the subpatterns (0: match of whole pattern, 1: match of first subpattern, etc.) but only the match of the whole pattern. And that will always contain the preceding non-alphabetic character, if there is any. One solution is to strip it from the match with `.replace(/^[\W\d_]/, "")` like this: `"(19".match(/(^|[\W\d_])\d+/g)[0].replace(/^[\W\d_]/, "")`.

Answer (score 0):

The regex would be:
`var regex = /@"[^"]*"/g;`

Answer (score 0):

Gumbo's regexp is very nice and all, however it fails to detect escaped quotes (e.g. `\"`, `\\\"`, etc.). A regexp that solves this is as follows:

```
/@(["'])[^]*?[^\\](?:\\\\)*\1|@""|@''/g
```

An explanation (continuing from Gumbo's explanation):

- `[^\\]` matches the nearest character preccedding the ending quote that is not a backslash (to anchor the back-slash count check).
- `(?:\\\\)*` matches only if the number of backslashes is a multiple of 2 (including zero) so that escaped backslashes are not counted.
- `|@""` checks to see if there is an empty double quote because `[^\\]` requires at least one character present in the string for it to work.
- `|@''` checks to see if there is an empty single quote.