# javascript simple replace everything within quotes

Tags: javascript, regex

Surprising but I am finding it hard to find an example regex which replaces text within quotes. E.g

1. `john went for a 'walk'`
2. `john "walk" went for` - you get the idea any order

Only the word walk would be replaced.

I did find this: [Regular Expressions - how to replace a character within quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4476812/regular-expressions-how-to-replace-a-character-within-quotes) but it seems mega complex for what I am wanting to do.

Comment: Try this with no `@`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6520407/javascript-regex-quote?rq=1

Comment: @Kobi perhaps if this question had a more meaningful title I(many others) would have found it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the JavaScript regex:

`/(["'])[^]*?\1/g`

This matches both anything that is in between double quotes or single quotes.

For your specific cases:

```
var s = "john went for a 'walk'";
s.replace(/(["'])[^]*?\1/g, "run");

// "john went for a run"
```

And:

```
var s = "john \"walk\" went for";
s.replace(/(["'])[^]*?\1/g, "run");

// "john run went for"
```

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
var string = "john went for a 'walk'";

var new_string = string.replace(/'([^;]*)'|"([^;]*)"/,"girl");
```

try http://jsfiddle.net/7dwCU/