# Javascript replace function will not remove quotes

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, string

I'm currently doing the following to remove extraneous characters and quotes from my strings:

```
console.log(word);
word = word.replace(/[.,\/#!$%\^&\*;:{}=\-_`~()]/g, "");
console.log(word);
word = word.replace(/["']/g, "");
console.log(word);
```

Many words are being scanned, but my output tends to be:
“If
“If
"If

OR

time,” 
time” 
time”

Is my regex wrong?

Comment: regex is ok - but wont remove `”` or `“` because they are not `"` (just look how different the characters are in this comment)

Comment: Might it be easier to approach this from the opposite direction with a list of allowed characters? E.g. `word.replace(/[^a-z\d\s]/gi, '');`

Comment: Do you know how long this list of characters is? Ever tried supporting multiple languages? Emoji?

Comment: Its look like you replace all unwords chars.
You can do it also `word.replace( /\W/g, "" )`

Comment: @MosheHarush `\W` matches spaces.

Comment: Maybe this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6520407/javascript-regex-quote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way to solve this would be to use the following, instead:

```
word = word.replace(/[^\w\s]/g, '');
```

`[^ ... ]` - inverted selection

`\w` - matches alphanumerics, regardless of case

`\s` - matches spaces

Comment: Also `word.replace(/(?!\s)\W/g, '');`

Comment: @MosheHarush - Ok... but that's not nearly as clear.